# java.sql.SQLException: Closed statement: next

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following method which uses JDBC to get data from the DB:

```
public List<QueryHolder> getData(String Name) throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource ds;
    ds = new OracleDataSource();

    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.***.*.**:1521/dbg";
    ds.setURL(url);
    Connection conn = null;
    conn=ds.getConnection("name","password");

    SQL_Str = "SELECT ASM4EVLENMEEHLIYETBELGESI.DAMATSOYAD,ASM4EVLENMEEHLIYETBELGESI.DAMATBABAADI,ASM4EVLENMEEHLIYETBELGESI.DAMATANNEADI FROM ASM4EVLENMEEHLIYETBELGESI where DAMATSOYAD like ('%"
            + Name + "%')";
    Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
    if (ps == null)
        throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
    rs = ps.executeQuery(SQL_Str);
    ps.close();
    if (con != null) {
        con.close();
    }

    if (rs == null)
        throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
    List<QueryHolder> list = new ArrayList<QueryHolder>();
    while (rs.next()) {                                 // <-- This is line 89.
        QueryHolder que = new QueryHolder();

        que.setSoyad(rs.getString("DAMATSOYAD"));
        que.setBabaadi(rs.getString("DAMATANNEADI"));
        que.setAnneadi(rs.getString("DAMATBABAADI"));

        list.add(que);
    }
    return list;
}
```

However, when I run this method, it throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed statement: next
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:187)
    Que.Query.getData(Query.java:89)
    ...
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You close the connection and the statement *before* you access the result set. You have to close them **after** you have processed everything.

Answer (score 3):

Correct closing order :

The following procedures should be done (in order)

1. ResultSet
2. PreparedStatement
3. Connection.

> Edited code

```
Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
...
rs = ps.executeQuery(SQL_Str);
...

while (rs.next()) {                                 // <-- This is line 89.
    ...
}

ps.close();
con.close();
return list;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to keep you `ps.close();` or other closing statements in the `finally` block. Instead of handling `Exception` on the method label use `try and catch` instead.

the problem in your case is you closed the Statement before and trying to iterate through the ResultSet to just put your `ps.close();` after the `while` block

**Edit**:
do it something like this

```
public returnType methodname()
{
    try{
        //your boilerplate code
        return whateverYouWantToReturn;
    }
    catch(AppropriateExceptionClass e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
     //closing statements
    }
 return null;
}
```

Comment: Because it is returning something, try catch caused problems.

Comment: returning means what return it in try

Answer (score 1):

The execution of

```
ps.close();
```

is in the wrong place.

You have to close the Statement after having iterate on its result set (that is, just close ps after the while loop).